# Angular ng-hide with a dynamic flag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which has row grouping based on one of the fields value. The grouping is working. I am using `ng-hide` to expand and collapse. By default i want the first group to be expanded and other groups to collapse. i was using a flag variable like `ng-hide="flag"`.

This flag was causing all the groups to either expand or collapse.

can i set this flag conditionally on runtime based on which `ng-hide` works dynamically.
I have tried adding a javascript function and calling it in ng-hide="funct()"
that did not work.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups" class="ng-cloak"  >
      <tr  >
           <td class="ng-cloak"  >

               <a href="" ng-click="flag = !flag" >
            <span ng-show="flag"><i class="icon-fixed-width">&#xf067;</i></span>
    <span ng-show="!flag"><i class="icon-fixed-width">&#xf068;</i></span>

                </a>
                {{group.value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr   ng-hide ="flag" ng-repeat="x in group.data | filter:query| orderBy:predicate:reverse " >

</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dTPvE/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ng-init` directive to initialize the flag with a function call:

```
<tr ng-init="flag = someFunction()">
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/J5mY3/) to demonstrate this example.
Here's an updated demo using your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/dTPvE/2/.

Comment: Tried it but the expand and toggle is not working fine for the any groups.I am not sure where i went wrong.

Comment: @user3445114 see my other update. It works fine as long as you init the flag insinde each ng-repeat directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it working as expected. Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can use $index og ng-repeat. There are different variable of ng-repeat, $index,$first,$last etc.
You use somthing like

ng-hide="$index==1"

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init` like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups" class="ng-cloak" ng-init="flag = !$first">
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dTPvE/4/